# Ignore a Query String when using ajaxComplete (settings.url)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using ajaxComplete to catch AJAX requests, the only problem is that I can't catch the /cart.js because there's always a random Query String.

ex- '*/cart.js?_=1324346569*'

How can I tell ajaxComplete to ignore query strings so my code picks up on just '/cart.js'?

My code is the following -

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
    if (settings.url === "/cart.js") {
        console.log('caught cart.js even tho it has these query parameters');
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (settings.url.includes("/cart.js")) {
  // ....
}
```